# UWP Strikethrough

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'd like to use strikethrough in a UWP app. For example: '10% off <del>£100</del> £90.' The advice seems to be to use TextDecorations, which in 2012 was still not available ([link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cba0c363-60da-4e4e-9fc1-93f7c3658aff/textdecorations-in-textblock?forum=winappswithcsharp)). Please can you tell me if it's possible to use strikethrough in a TextBlock now?

Answer (score 2):

According to the offical [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.textdecorations), strikethrough is an available TextDecoration.

An XAML-Example:

```
<!-- Use the default font values for the strikethrough text decoration. -->
<TextBlock
  TextDecorations="Strikethrough"
  FontSize="36" >
  The quick red fox
</TextBlock>
```

I tested the example by myself in an UWP-Application and had no problems.

How Rob mentioned:
It is available since v10.0.15063.0.

Comment: I tested this earlier on the project I've been working on for a while and it didn't work. Just tried it on a brand new test UWP-Application and it works fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Updating the minimum version of Universal Windows to 15063 has got my main project working.

Comment: Note that the documentation linked here is for WPF and doesn't apply to UWP apps. UWP apps use Windows.UI.Text.TextDecorations as documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.textdecorations . This does include Strikethrough and is available starting with the Windows 10 Creators Update (introduced v10.0.15063.0

Comment: Good Point! I will Change that