# How to draw an eye catching horizontal line crossing the text in a textblock in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to do something like this.

[image]

The TextStyle attribute doesn't provide something similar. Are there any way to implement this easily?

**Update**:

Thanks for the answer about using the TextDecoration. However, it is  a little too thin and could not be in different color. Is there any more flexible solution?

Comment: Share any code you might have written.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UWP Strikethrough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48580945/uwp-strikethrough)

Comment: It would help if you show us the part of the XAML you already have...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solved the problem myself. I use binding to draw a custom line over the TextBlock. Line end points are derived from TextBlock size and offset returned by the binding properties.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textLabel" Text="HelloWOrld}" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.RightOf="visibleUI" DoubleTapped="OnEditNameBegin"  />
            
<Line Name="crossOutLine"  Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="4" 
                  X1="{x:Bind LayerData.nameLabelX1, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  Y1="{x:Bind LayerData.nameLabelY1, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  X2="{x:Bind LayerData.nameLabelX2, Mode=OneWay}" 
                  Y2="{x:Bind LayerData.nameLabelY2, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

binding part:

```
public float nameLabelX1 { get => 0; }
public float nameLabelY1 { get => (float)textLabel.DesiredSize.Height /2; }
public float nameLabelX2 { get => (float)textLabel.DesiredSize.Width;}
public float nameLabelY2 { get => nameLabelY1; }
```

Comment: Nice to see you doing a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>**Note 1:** Although this is not what OP wants, I'll keep this for reference.</sub>

<sup>**Note 2:** I am also aware "this is not a line (object, red) crossing text". But since the intended graphical output is similar, I opted for this out-of-the-box-solution.</sup>

---

If you don't mind the color, you can use the strikethrough decoration:

```
<TextBlock TextDecorations="Strikethrough">Hellow World</TextBlock>
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.text.textdecorations?view=winrt-20348

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's what I need. However, the line is a little too thin.

Comment: Then, unfortunately, you'll need a custom implementation - I'll keep this answer for reference.